# Oracle MERGE does not INSERT

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, replace, upsert

I have this simple example I can't seems to get working :

```
MERGE INTO mytable  mt
USING dual
ON (mt.id = 'AAA' )  
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET mt.name = 'updated'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (mt.id , mt.name )
    VALUES ('AAA', 'Gooood' );
```

If a 'AAA' record exists in the table, it is updated successfully.

But if does not exists, it is not inserted :

```
Affected rows: 0
Time: 0.003ms
```

Any clue on what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: What tool are you using that responds "Affected rows: 0 Time: 0.003ms"?

Comment: One wonders if the OP is merging without commit in one session and querying from another.  Or whether the existing app is correctly interpreting output from the analog of SQL%ROWCOUNT.

Comment: Is it possible your table `mytable` requires more than just `id` and `name` to do a valid insert?

Comment: @Tony Andrews : Sorry for late answer, I had to do it another way ...
The tool I used back then was Navicat for Oracle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Works for me:

```
SQL> create table mytable (id varchar(3), name varchar(30));

Table created.

SQL> MERGE INTO mytable  mt
  2  USING dual
  3  ON (mt.id = 'AAA' )  
  4  WHEN MATCHED THEN 
  5      UPDATE SET mt.name = 'updated'
  6  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
  7      INSERT (mt.id , mt.name )
  8      VALUES ('AAA', 'Gooood' );

1 row merged.

SQL> select * from mytable;

ID  NAME
--- ------------------------------
AAA Gooood
```

Comment: I use Oracle 9.2 ... I heard MERGE function is "better" on Oracle 10 :-/